# steam: missing libGL.so.1 and libdrm.so.2

Tags: 17.10, steam, opengl, mesa

I am attempting to install `steam` from the ubuntu repos on Xubuntu 17.10, and am running into a dependecy issue.

Steam requires these two 32bit libraries:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     steam:i386 : Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I attempt to install them:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Conflicts: libgl1
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any ideas?